# loop through a column in csv file to get requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a file_1.csv with one 'url' column. 
I want to run get.request for an API link in each row.
Then I want to export the output into a json file. 
I used the below script.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import numpy


df = pd.read_csv('file_1', header = 0)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r = requests.get(row['url'])
    data = json.loads(r.text)
with open('file_1','w') as d:
    json.dump(data,d)
```

The script is working but it is showing the result of only one row.
Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: you are overwriting the data variable for every iteration. Might be best to append to an empty list

Comment: why are you opening the file and then using pandas?

Comment: The only reason for that is that I am a python beginner. I am going to delete that line.

Comment: @J.Doe ok well you can get rid of your `with` block and just use something like `df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`. No need to open it first

Comment: @ SuperStew done. Thank you. But this does not answer my original question. How to loop the request for every row?

Comment: @Chris How can I do this?

Comment: @J.Doe add `data = []` above the for loop before iterations then instead of data = json... do `data.append(json...)` something like that should work

Comment: @ Chris I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Answer is:**

```
df= pd.read_csv('file.csv', header = 0)
row_iterator = df.iterrows()
_, last = row_iterator.__next__()`
for i, row in row_iterator:
   r= requests.get(row["url"])
   r= requests.get(last["url"])
   last = row
   data = (r.text)
```

****This loops on each row and gets the request in string format.****